# Select where bit is not 0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have made the following query to select a record that isn't `0`.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Bit != 1 OR Bit IS NULL;
```

Why is the check `Bit != 1` not enough for a nullable `BIT`?

Comment: `where bool is distinct from true` would be ANSI SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See following results:

- `'true' != 'true'` → false
- `'false' != 'true'` → true
- `NULL != 'true'` → null (and equivalent to false in `WHERE` because it is not true)

What you can do is use `COALESCE` to change null into 'false'

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE COALESCE(Bool, 'false') != 'true';
```